# (c++) Error somewhere between return and function output

Tags: c++, calculator

Hello I am having a problem in my C++ program (pythagorean theorem) somewhere in between returning my value to the function and getting the output using cout.

For example if I set `a` to 3, `b` to 0, and `c` to 2, when running the program and watching my variables, the output is either 0 or nan. Here is more info on the variables:

> pyth_b_1 - (error) Not available in current context! p_t() - (error) {float (float, float, float)} 0x4014ad

Code:

```
cout<<"Set one value 0 to get answer for that variable \n";
        cout<<"Enter number or 0 for 'a': ";
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"Enter number or 0 for 'b': ";
        cin>>b;
        cout<<"Enter number or 0 for 'c': ";
        cin>>c;
        cout<<"You'r answer = "<<p_t(a, b, c)<<endl;
```

Code:

```
float p_t(float a,float b,float c){

    if(a == 0 && b != 0 && c != 0){
    // 0 equals nothing for parameters
    cout<<"You chose to find a"<<endl;
    float pyth_c = (pow(c, 2)) - (pow(b, 2));
    float pyth_a  = sqrt(pyth_c);
    return pyth_a;
    }
    else if(a != 0 && b == 0 && c != 0){
    float pyth_c_1 = (pow(c, 2)) - (pow(a, 2));
    float pyth_b_1 = sqrt(pyth_c_1);
    return pyth_b_1;
    }
    else if(a != 0 && b != 0 && c == 0){
    float pyth_a_2 = (pow(a, 2)) - (pow(b, 2));
    return pyth_a_2;
    }

    }
```

Comment: In case 1 if `c` < `b` then `pyth_c` will be negative. You then try to take it's square root.  Same in all the other cases.  Except case 3 is missing the square root call. This is a perfect program to lean how to use your debugger.

Comment: I suggest learning to use a debugger. It will make programming infinitely easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to your code, when a == 3, b == 0, c == 2, we get: `pyth_c = pow(2, 2) - pow(3, 2)`, what gives `4 - 9 == -5`. You can't take square root of that negative number (in real numbers at least).

Comment: Thank you very much. I rewrote my code to only allow positive numbers and restart the program if not. Thanks again.